# FOR LOOPS BUGS IN RunJS

Tags: javascript

Ok guys here is the code lines which have been run with RunJS and da console of google chrome:
{sorry if I have shown da result in details}

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Jack is a fantastic programmer");
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    console.log("AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him");
  }
}
```

and I've got different results. so here is the RunJS's BUG :

```
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'

/////////////////////////////////////////////////RunJS//////////////////////////////////
```

In fact the code based on da "C" programming for loops must be like this :

```
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'Jack is a fantastic programmer'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
'AND NOBODY IS LIKE Him'
////////////////////////////////////////C & da Console////////////////////////
```

So here is the code trace :
RUNJS :
0 to 5 , 5 times of this string "JACK IS A FANTASTIC PROGRAMMER"
seperated
0 to 5 , 5 times multiply by 0 to 4 , 4 times which is equal to 20 , so
20 times of this string "AND NOBODY IS LIKE HIM"

WHICH IS WRONG.
MY RunJS has been lately updated.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're seeing in RunJS is because you have the 'Match Lines' options turned on.